# Set Parameters RDLC Report C#

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

In my rdlc report I create parameter test. In form I write below code to set parameter:

```
//Set Parameters
ReportParameter[] p = new ReportParameter[1];
p[0] = new ReportParameter("Test", "Testing");
currentBilling_rv.LocalReport.SetParameters(p);

// Provide datasource to report Current_Total_Billing.rdlc
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("CurrentTotalBilling", dataset.Tables[2]);
currentTotalBilling_rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
currentTotalBilling_rv.LocalReport.DisplayName = "Current Total Billing";
currentTotalBilling_rv.LocalReport.ReportPath = ".\\Current_Total_Billing.rdlc";
currentTotalBilling_rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
currentTotalBilling_rv.RefreshReport();
```

When I run the program I have exception

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.MissingReportSourceException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
>
> Additional information: The source of the report definition has not
>   been specified

Please help.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the parameter related code?

Comment: Yes, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are setting a parameter for a `ReportViewer` named `currentBilling_rv` not for `currentTotalBilling_rv` which is used in the next lines of code.

If `currentBilling_rv` name is correct verify that `currentBilling_rv.LocalReport.ReportPath` is compiled.

Comment: Yes you are right. I correct the report viewer name. But still face same error. Then I put "currentTotalBilling_rv.LocalReport.SetParameters(p);" after provide datasource. then I have error in processing mode.